# What is the sample space of this experiment?

Tags: probability

In an experiment, a coin is flipped continually until it comes up heads, at which point the experiment stops. What is the sample space of this experiment? If E25 is the event that less than 25 flips are required to complete the experiment, how many outcomes are contained in E25?

Comment: $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample space is the set of all possible outcomes, in this case,
$$\{t^nh\mid n\ge 0\}$$
If we restrict the sequence length to less than $25$, then it is easy to see that there are $24$ sequences in the above set with this property.

Answer (score 0):

Did has given you an appropriate sample space. The more interesting question is, what should we take as our $\sigma$-algebra, $\mathscr{F}$.

Williams (*Probability with Martingales*, page 24) suggests

$$\mathscr{F} := \sigma( \{\omega \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}: \omega_n = a\} : n \in \mathbb{N}, a \in \{0,1\}). $$

It is interesting to note that $\mathscr{F} \neq \mathscr{P}( \{0,1\})^{\mathbb{N}}$, which you can check by calculating the cardinatlies of these two sets.